# how to play a specific timestamp in a video file using django 3

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to create a website similar to http://playphrase.me in this project the user searches for a word or phrase and then short video clips of that phrase being used in different movies and tv series is played for the user.
In my views.py, i search srt subtitles for a keyword or phrase and then get the name, url path, and the timestamp during which a word or phrase is being said in a video file. I can send these info in a json or dict to template, my problem is how to play these files. I want my video player to start and stop playing a video at the specific timestamp that i provided.
Please tell me which video player to use and how.

Answer (score 0):

html5 has the following attribute that you can add to any video

http://example.com/video.mp4#t=5,10

This will start the video at t=5, and stop at t=10.

https://web.dev/video-and-source-tags/#specify-start-and-end-times

Comment: Thnx a lot. Appreciate it.